# Dispatch to props only when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The issue I am having is that the mapDispatchToProps is getting sent as a whole, where I want it to only send if I click on the button delete.

This is my class, its fetching the fetchList good, everything is working as expected but when I've added the delete button its seems to mess it all up, it seems to call the delete for every refresh on the page, any idea why?

Could it be the `render()` where I create the `Button` maybe it gets triggered without me clicking it? Just by creating the list, because it gets triggered for every occasion that each itemInList gets created via the map.

```
class List extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchList();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.newItem) {
            this.props.list.unshift(nextProps.newItem);
        }
    }

    onDelete = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteItem(id);
    }

    render() {
        const listItems = this.props.list.map(itemInList => (
            <div key={itemInList.id}> 
                <h3 className="title__font smaller">{itemInList.title} 
                    <Button 
                        btnType="Delete" 
                        onClick={this.onDelete(itemInList.id)}>
                        <i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </Button>
                </h3>
                <p className="body__font">{itemInList.body}</p>
            </div>
        ));
        return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="title__font">List</h1>
            { listItems }
        </div>
        );
    };
};

List.propTypes = {
    fetchList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    list: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    newItem: PropTypes.object
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    list: state.list.items,
    newItem: state.list.item
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchList: () => dispatch( actions.fetchList() ),
        deleteItem: (id) => dispatch( actions.deleteItem(id) )
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List);
```

This is the actions for the delete item:

```
export const deleteItem = (id) => dispatch => {
    console.log(id);
    dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.DELETE_ITEM,
        payload: filtered
    })
};
```

That log gets triggered 10 times in the actions file.

Comment: `onClick={()=>this.onDelete(itemInList.id)}`

Comment: You're calling `onDelete` immediately so, it will dispatch on render.

Comment: Oh right, I figured that was the case, thanks guys! Only new to Redux! @BoyWithSilverWings

Comment: That is not a redux issue, it's a react issue. It happened because you passed a function invocation to the onClick property when you really wanted to pass a function declaration. `this.onDelete` is the declaration, `this.onDelete()` is an invocation of said declaration. For more information please refer to react's [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to pass a function declaration into `onClick` and you'll need to pass the `id` in somehow. We don't want to declare any functions in the render method for performance issues, but we need some way to pass the `id` into the method upon invocation. Data attributes are a great solution to this problem.

Here is some relevant documentation.

- [React: Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)
- [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)
- [babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties.html)

First, ensure the `this` context of your method is bound to the component as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(prop)

  this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this)
}
```

The above is required because class methods are actually defined on their prototype and not on individual instantiations. Side note: If you're using a build system that has something along the lines of babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties you could declare your method as follows:

```
onDelete = (e) => { this.props.deleteItem(e.target.dataset.id) }
```

You'll need to update your `onDelete` method as follows:

```
onDelete = (e) => {
  this.props.deleteItem(e.target.dataset.id);
}
```

and you'll also need to update the `Button` markup in your render method like this:

```
<Button
    btnType="Delete"
    data-id={itemInList.id}
    onClick={this.onDelete}
>
    <i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
</Button>
```

EDIT:

Here is a working [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1y67x3m6q4) to demonstrate how it all works. I had to make some changes to your code such as excluding the non-included `<Button/>` component. I hope this helps you get where you need to be.

Comment: I have attempted to do as you have stated above but still I can not get it to trigger when it gets clicked, not sure why this is...

Comment: Please post your updated component code. (are you binding the `this` context of your component method?) If not, check my update.

Comment: Hi @Kyle Richardson, Sorry for the late reply, this is a gist showing the code - https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/ad0074d96b875636ee73f9c2bb8d0db1  I have tried to do everything stated above but yet no trigger when clicked.

Comment: I think the issue it coming from the button, since its a component in mine, this is the buttton component: `const button = (props) => (
    <button
      disabled={props.disabled} 
      className={["Button", [props.btnType]].join(' ')}
      onClick={props.clicked}>{props.children}
    </button>
);`

Comment: Yup, the problem is your component! You pass `props.clicked` to the `onClick` property of your button, but when you use your `Button` component in your list you give it an `onClick` property instead of a `clicked` property. I advise you to use standardized property names such as `onClick` on your custom components. As an aside; you should defube [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) for your custom components. It will help you catch mistakes like this during development.

Comment: I also recommending setting up a transpiler in your build process such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and using [babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types)

Comment: Yeah I figured it out earlier today and posted the answer, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `onDelete` immediately, so it will dispatch on render.

Try replacing:

```
onDelete = (id) => {
  this.props.deleteItem(id);
}
```

with

```
onDelete = (id) => () => this.props.deleteItem(id);
```

Comment: Do you know why its not getting triggered now after changing it all up? I've tried changing the button onClick and the function. @Jon Koops

Comment: For some reason its still not getting triggered, this is very weird @Jon Koops, thanks for your help though, I've done this project in order to learn redux better hehe.

Comment: How is the id be passed into the method through the onClick? This solution is missing some things.

Comment: @KyleRichardson what do you mean? The returned function has `id`in scope as far as I can see.

Comment: @JonKoops  But how is the id being passed into the method in the first place? As an example, `onClick={this.onDelete}` Where is the id? an event object will be passed to the method by React. This is why I suggested using data attributes in my solution. The `data-id` value you can be accessed in the method through `e.traget.dataset.id`.

Comment: `{this.onDelete(itemInList.id)}`?

Comment: That will still be invoked on the rendering of the component, not on click. You need to pass a function declaration to `onClick`, not an invocation. Please refer to React's [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) documentation. It works differently than HTML's `onclick`.

Comment: The `onDelete` function returns another function, that function is called by React's `onClick`. It's basically a currying pattern. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Nope... I was the one missing something. I completely overlooked the curry. I must apologize for that! Chalk it up to a brain fart?